# Migration issue from Oracle Fusion MiddleWare from 11gR1 to 12cR2 and deployment in Weblogic 12c standalone server

Tags: oracle, migration, weblogic

I am currently working on an enterprise application which is developed in jDeveloper 11g Release 1, Oracle 11g Database, standalone WebLogic server  10.3. We are planning to migrate the whole application into 12c.

Our application runs smoothly in jDeveloper 12.2.1.3 version in Integrated environment after migration. However we are facing trouble when we tried to deploy the application (.ear file) in standalone weblogic 12.2.1.3.

We had to migrate the Oracle database from 11gR1 to 12c. After resolving numerous errors, we have successfully logged in to the system, and get into our `Welcome.jsf` page. Now, we facing a error when rendering view object in dynamic tabshell. Basically, the view object fails to render in dynamic UI shell.

```
<Jan 15, 2019 10:23:21,487 AM BDT> <Error> <oracle.adfinternal.controller.application.model.SaveStateTokenListener> <BEA-000000> <ADFc: ViewScope not available in this environment, cannot save State-token.>
taskflowId= /tmPageFlows/day-start-flow.xml#day-start-flow
<Jan 15, 2019 10:23:30,797 AM BDT> <Emergency> <oracle.dfw.incident> <BEA-000000> <incident 21 created with problem key "ADFC-00032 [ADFc]">
<Jan 15, 2019 10:23:31,109 AM BDT> <Warning> <oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.context.RichExceptionHandler> <BEA-000000> <ADF_FACES-60098:Faces lifecycle receives unhandled exceptions in phase RESTORE_VIEW 1
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at oracle.adf.controller.internal.binding.TaskFlowRegionController.getViewPortState(TaskFlowRegionController.java:481)
        at oracle.adf.controller.internal.binding.TaskFlowRegionController.evaluateViewInputParameters(TaskFlowRegionController.java:442)
        at oracle.adf.controller.internal.binding.TaskFlowRegionController.doRegionRefresh(TaskFlowRegionController.java:233)
        at oracle.adf.controller.internal.binding.TaskFlowRegionController.refreshRegion(TaskFlowRegionController.java:145)
        at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer.internalRefreshControl(DCBindingContainer.java:3343)
        at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer.refresh(DCBindingContainer.java:3005)
        at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer.internalRefreshControl(DCBindingContainer.java:3334)
        at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer.refresh(DCBindingContainer.java:3005)
        at oracle.adf.controller.v2.lifecycle.PageLifecycleImpl.prepareModel(PageLifecycleImpl.java:113)
        at oracle.adf.controller.faces.lifecycle.FacesPageLifecycle.prepareModel(FacesPageLifecycle.java:387)
        at leads.capita.bs.exception.core.CapitaCustomPageLifeCycle.prepareModel(CapitaCustomPageLifeCycle.java:52)
        at oracle.adf.controller.v2.lifecycle.Lifecycle$2.execute(Lifecycle.java:158)
        at oracle.adfinternal.controller.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:201)
        at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFPhaseListener.startPageLifecycle(ADFPhaseListener.java:204)
        at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFPhaseListener$1.after(ADFPhaseListener.java:370)
        at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFPhaseListener.afterPhase(ADFPhaseListener.java:89)
        at oracle.adfinternal.controller.faces.lifecycle.ADFLifecyclePhaseListener.afterPhase(ADFLifecyclePhaseListener.java:53)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executeAfterPhaseLogic(LifecycleImpl.java:459)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:381)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:227)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:650)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
        at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:207)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:105)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:529)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:529)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:354)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:232)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
        at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:169)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
        at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:169)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
        at leads.capita.master.filter.CapitaSessionFilter.doFilter(CapitaSessionFilter.java:146)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$3.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:172)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:650)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:110)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilterInternal(JpsAbsFilter.java:273)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:147)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:94)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
        at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:248)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:32)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3701)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3667)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2443)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2291)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2269)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1703)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1663)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
        at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
        at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)
>
```